# Dataproc Connection Refused and Connection reset by peer

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a job that get messages from an on-premise kafka and send it to BigQuery using Dataproc. But sometimes I get both bellow exceptions that causes my job to fail.

**ConnectionRefused**:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From <worker-3>/<ip> to <worker-1>:50267 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor44.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
    ... 15 more
```

I checked the items listed in http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused.

On the exception, we can see that:

> "Call From **worker-3**/**ip** to **worker-1**:50267"

Communication between workers on a unknown port (?) (50267)

And sometimes with:

> "Call From **master-node**/**ip** to **master-node**:**8020**"

Communication in master on NameNode metadata service port (8020).

On another reference https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message, it says:

> The message 'Connection Refused' has two main causes:
>
> 1. Nothing is listening on the IP:Port you are trying to connect to.
> 2. The port is blocked by a firewall.

Shouldn't this be handled by Dataproc?

**Connection reseted by peer**:

```
Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer; Host Details : local host is: "<master-node>/<ip>"; destination host is: "<master-node>":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.MRJobLauncher.<init>(MRJobLauncher.java:166)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.<init>(CliMRJobLauncher.java:59)
    at gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher.main(CliMRJobLauncher.java:111)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:520)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:979)
```

My thoughts are that both errors are pretty generic and happened inside the Dataproc cluster, not related to my application. Am I correct? I'm using a retry aproach to resolve my problem right now. But I would like to understand why these errors occur in a Hadoop-based product like Dataproc and if I have a way to avoid them? Shouldn't Dataproc take care of all of it for the users?

Comment: This is unexpected and should not happen. However, we'll need additional information to get to the bottom of this (logs, etc). Kindly open a support case, or reach out to dataproc-feedback@google.com (only Dataproc engineers can see your messages). dataproc-feedback@ is best effort.

Comment: You can also [create](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187133) a new Cloud Dataproc issue on the [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) page. If you do so, please post the issue ID.